# Animsition not working when in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, script-tag

For some reason, I keep getting 404 not found errors when I launch my code in flask for animsition, even though I'm pretty sure that I'm linking to it correctly in the static file. The line in particular that is messed up is this one, I believe:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename ='vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js')}}'"></script>
```

I checked and this is the proper location of the animsition file. Does this seem like proper syntax, or is the problem something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Where in the file are you loading the script?

Comment: @Itd9938 I'm loading the script at the end of the file before the </body> tag

Comment: @IzzyChong is your file located inside the `/static/` directory? like, `/static/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js` ?

Comment: @IzzyChong Check the rendered html and see what exactly flask outputs for this script src.

Comment: Do you have an extra quotation mark in your url? `"{{url_for('static', filename ='vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js')}}'"`. See the additional quote at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra quotation mark in your URL?

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename ='vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js')}}'"></script>
```

I mean this:

```
.....ion.min.js')}}'"></script>
```

Can you change it to:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename ='vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and see if it loads? Your syntax seems to be fine.

Comment: is it accepted now? sorry i'm new to this forum haha